# html + php form does not send emails

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I know it had been asked a lot here, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The form should send emails with data from form.

```
<form class="myform" action="contact.php" method="post">
<p class="nadform">Zapisz sie do naszego klubu!</p>
<input id="in1" class="polefor" name="firstname" type="text"
 placeholder="IMIĘ" /> <input id="in2" class="polefor" name="email"
 type="email" placeholder="ADRES EMAIL" /> <input id="wyślij" 
name="submit" type="submit" value="ZAPISZ SIĘ" />
```

And here is said contact.php:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$mail_to = 'emailadres';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
$body_message = 'firstname'.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Dziękujemy za rejestrację.');
    window.location = 'pageadres';
</script>
```

It does not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting any errors in your error log or on screen?

Comment: It seams its all ok. But Email is not sent.

Comment: If you get rid of $headers in your mail function does it work?

Comment: Doesnt seam to change anything.

Comment: Are you able to test this code on another host? Maybe your server isn't configured to work with the `mail()` function. I know if you are running this on your local PC with WAMP, there is some extra configuration you must do to use the mail function.

Comment: Another form used to run on this server, so it souldnt be the case. Isnt there any error in my code?

Comment: Did the other form send an email?